# How do I fix this encoding error in the Python binary in my pygame project?

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm trying to setup a project in PyCharm, but I get an error when I try to execute it.

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xca' in file /Users/raddevon/PycharmProjects/pygame/env-pygame/bin/python on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I've setup a virtual environment for my project and have installed PyGame in the virtual environment. This generated a different error until I installed the PyGame binaries for Mac on my system. Now, I'm stuck at another point.

When I opened the project in PyCharm, I expected it would detect the virtual environment and configure the interpreter automatically, but I had to do this manually. I have done so and that seemed to work, but I am unable to execute due to this error.

EDIT: I had configured the IDE to try running Python with the Python interpreter rather than the script I actually wanted to run. I've got a new error now, but at least I'm making progress. Thanks to @nightcracker for setting me on the right path.

Comment: What are the contents of `/Users/raddevon/PycharmProjects/pygame/env-pygame/bin/python`? What do you execute?

Comment: @nightcracker You sent me in the right direction. This being the first time I had manually configured the interpreter, I mis-interpreted (heh) the configuration and had the interpreter trying to run itself. I have corrected that, and I'm now running into a different error. Off to research that for a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try adding the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the top of your sourcefiles?

As the error message suggests you may want to visit [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and then declare the encoding as I proposed above.

Comment: I vaguely understood the encoding thing, but the error seems to say the encoding problem is within Python itself which is why I hadn't tried anything on my source files. I only have a single file at the moment. I tried adding that to my file, but I get the same error.

Comment: So perhaps as @nightcracker suggests, you could give us more detail. Can you show us how do you execute and the contents of the problematic file?

Comment: I found the problem. See my original post. It was stupidity on my part. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out. Good luck ! :)